# Do Neo4j remote shell connections leave open sessions behind when not exited by :quit?

Tags: neo4j

Do Neo4j remote shell connections leave open sessions behind when not exited by `:quit`?

If there are open sessions is there anyway to run a job to close those open connections?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you have the connection open, obviously there is going to be a "connection" ... but unless you are running a query, there will be no database-session. Which (connection or session) do you mean ?

Comment: I start a remote session from my notebook to my Neo4j DB remotely. If I forget to `:quit` and just close the window will there be an open session that stays open?

Comment: No, there won't be a database-session open ... because there's none running (it would be different if you were running a long running query and then closed the window). The connection will remain open for a while and then be cleaned up.